# Scrollview is not scrolling to the bottom

Tags: swift, scrollview

I'm struggling with how ScrollView works.  I watched the video tutorials on scrollview where you have to add a scrollview, then UIView, then added constraints, and set View Controller to be of freeform and set the height to 1000.

In my app, I'm loading 3 coupons which are image views, and these image views are set programmatically.  Here is the code, can anyone please help me with scrollViews?  Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var UIView: UIView!

struct MyCoupons {
    static var couponsString: UIImage?
    static var siteCoupons: [String?] = []
    static var count: Int = 0
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var i: Int = 0
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
    var width: Int = 0
    var height: Int = 0

    ViewController.PopulateDataCoupons()

    i=0
    height = 300
    repeat {
        let imageName = MyCoupons.siteCoupons[i]//"Coupons1.jpg"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

        y = i * height + 50
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: y, width: 250, height: 300)

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        i += 1

    }
        while (i < MyCoupons.count-1)
}

public class func PopulateDataCoupons() {
    var i = 0
    var abc: String


    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Coupons", ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
            let myStrings = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            abc = myStrings.joined(separator: ",")

            let couponsArr = abc.components(separatedBy: ",")
            print("couponsArr.count", couponsArr.count)

            repeat {
                MyCoupons.siteCoupons.append(couponsArr[i])
                i+=1
            } while i < ((couponsArr.count)-1)

            MyCoupons.count = couponsArr.count
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

}
[image: Scrollers show but it won't go down after the bottom hits]

[image: Constraints]

Comment: Did you try populating the coupons in viewDidLoad()? It looks like you are inserting coupons after views are appeared, including the scrollview.

Comment: Hi there, they are in viewDidAppear.  I called the function to viewDidLoad() as well, but still no luck.  The coupons images are appearing, but it's just at the 3rd coupon, it's cut off and doesn't scroll on to the next page.  I also have set Paging to enabled for the scrollView.

Comment: user interaction is enabled, right?

Comment: Yes, user interaction is enabled too.

Comment: Sorry I am not expert at scrollview but try adding scrollview delegate.

Comment: You should be adding the coupon views inside of the scroll view or some sort of container view that sits inside of the scroll view. It seems to me like you're not adding it within the scroll view but rather the superview or the scrollview. If you could post your view hiearchy and constraints and what not that would also help to see what else might need to be changed

Comment: Hi there, I have posted my Constraints.  Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: It's already solved.  See comment below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your images to the view of your viewController, not to your scrollView.
Your viewController height is 1000 and you've got a vertical offset of 50 for each images.
It goes like this:
50 + 300 + 50 + 300 + 50 + 300 = 1050
It's over 1000

Comment: So how do I add my images to the scrollView programmatically?  Thanks.  By the way, I changed the height to 1200 instead of 1000 but still have problem.

Comment: Cool!!! I changed the line to  scrollView.addSubview(imageView) and it works.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, I did, but it won't increment bec my reputation is < 15.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
 let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height)
     self.scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```